# VS 2017 cannot publish but run web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem when I want to publish a web application on Visual Studio 2017.

As a foreword:
I moved from one Notebook (Win 7) to a notebook (Win 10) recently. I restored missing nuget packages.

I can run the application. But when I want to deploy to via file system or deployement package I get the following error:

```
Copying file fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg failed. Could not find file 'fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'.
```

My structure is:

```
/Content
/Content/fonts
/Content/css
```

and the "fonts" folder contains the missing file.

Can aynone help me out here and give me some hints what I need to check for that?

The application is MVC 5, asp.net 4.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The folder contains the missing file, but is that file a part of your solution? Look for that file in your "Solution Explorer" if required please use "Include in project".

Comment: It is part of the solution. Before I moved to the new computer I was able to publish. Thats all a bit weird. Correct me if I am wrong. But if it would not be part of the solution then the deployment tool would not try to copy it into the package. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I wonder why it says 'Copying file fonts\glyphicons...' when the file is in Content, shouldn't it be 'Copying file Content\fonts\glyphicons...'? Was that path different before you moved to a new computer? Just for trial, could you move your fonts folder outside Content and try it once?

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction. At any time (no idea when) there was a new additional fonts folder created. In this the files were missing. I excluded them from the project and it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know it's working now!

Comment: If you make it an answer instead of comment then I can and will mark it as solution.

Comment: Done, provided the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says 'Copying file fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg to ...' which means the solution is trying to find the file in fonts folder within the root of the application. However, according to your structure, the fonts directory is inside the 'Content' folder. You can either move the fonts folder in your root or exclude the missing files from the csproj file.